# Div position different in Chrome than other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have been beating my head against the wall, and finally decided to ask for help.  I have two menu drop downs that appear when mousing over and align with the links mouse over div.  The first one aligns great in all browsers, the second one aligns fine in all browsers EXCEPT for Chrome where it is off by about 10 px.  I have tried everything I can think of but cannot get the Chrome browser to align them like the rest.

You can see an example at http://www.brewawesome.com.  The two menus are "Beer Recipes" (perfectly aligned) and "My Beer Recipes" (misaligned).

Comment: Your menus are misaligned because your font-sizes don't appear to be the same between chrome and the other browsers

Comment: Not sure how that would happen.  I am not doing anything specific for font-sizes based on browser type...

Comment: see my answer, I have tried to explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menus aren't aligned properly as your font size in chrome is too small.  I think it is due to the `font-variant:small-caps` property.  This changes your words to uppercase but as the size of a letter in the lowercase of the font.

In chrome, this seems to make the text extra small. You could try to use `text-transform:uppercase;` which should change all the menus fonts to be the same size in each browser.  If you then need to change the font-size to be smaller, you can just apply css font-size to it and that should give you a more cross browser friendly way of capitalising your words

If you have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kRsAM/) in different browsers, you will see you have a better rendering and closer match to each other in terms of size of the text done with text transform than you do with that done with variant

Comment: Pete, greatly appreciated!  That did the trick.  Thank you for providing a solution to the root problem instead of just a hack on top of it!  If I could give you double points I would.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome-specific css and reduce the positioning from the left

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 #divMyBeerRecipes{left:97px;} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second menu use

```
<div id="divMyBeerRecipes" class="menubody" style="height: 100px; left: 26.8%; display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

For #header change font-size: 12px; to font-size: 13px;